# Shell not honoring interpreter?

Tags: python, shell, ssl

I downloaded Python 3.4 sources, built the sources, and installed them in `/usr/local`. `make test` ran fine.

```
$ ls /usr/local/bin/ | grep python
python3
python3.4
python3.4-config
python3.4m
python3.4m-config
python3-config
```

I've got a little script that tries to use SNI. SNI has been giving me trouble in Python (re: [wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_hostname'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387651/wrap-socket-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-server-hostname)), and a newer version of Python is supposed to fix it. The script looks like so:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import sys, ssl, socket  

s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2 = ssl.wrap_socket(s1,
                     ca_certs="./pki/signing-dss-cert.pem",
                     cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                     ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
                     server_hostname="localhost")

s2.connect( ("localhost", 8443) )   

s2.send("GET / ")
time.sleep(1)
s2.send("HTTP/1.1")

s2.send("\r\n")
time.sleep(1)
s2.send("Hostname: localhost")
s2.send("\r\n")
s2.send("\r\n")
```

When I attempt to run it, I still receive that damn `TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_hostname'` error.

---

**EDIT**: I tried Lukas' suggestion below and changed the line to:

```
s2 = ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket(s1,
                     ca_certs="./pki/signing-dss-cert.pem",
                     cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                     ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
                     server_hostname="localhost")
```

Now, when I run the script my mouse pointer (the arrow that's slanted left) turns into the cross hairs (the plus sign) and I can drag boxes around the screen. After a minute or so, I get the following error:

```
$ ./fetch.sh
./fetch.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./fetch.sh: line 5: `s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)'
```

After the above fails and the pointer returns to normal, I actually have a single image of screen captures of the boxes I drew on the screen.

I'm beginning to think Python is a major pain in the ass and a waste of time. How can anyone justify two days of work when trying to do something simple like specifying a hostname in SSL?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong this time?

Comment: this sounds like you're accidentally running your program as shell script and not using the python interperter - in which case `import` would start imagemagick's `/usr/bin/import`, which would explain the cursor changing into crosshairs. Make sure you have the correct shebang at the beginning of the file, or start it using `python3 fetch.sh`...

Comment: @mata - you're right. I though that python3 might not be picking up its libs in `/usr/local/lib`, so I dropped a script called `python` in `/usr/local/bin` that set the path. The script was missing the `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 3):

The patch you're mentioning in the other question adds a `server_hostname` argument to the method [`ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/edb12dad7bf6/Lib/ssl.py#l336).

The function you're calling is [`ssl.wrap_socket`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/edb12dad7bf6/Lib/ssl.py#l838) however, which doesn't take a keyword argument `server_hostname`.

---

**Edit**: Try this:

```
from ssl import CERT_NONE
from ssl import PROTOCOL_SSLv23
from ssl import SSLSocket
import ssl, socket
import time


s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def wrap_socket_with_sni(sock, keyfile=None, certfile=None,
                         server_side=False, cert_reqs=CERT_NONE,
                         ssl_version=PROTOCOL_SSLv23, ca_certs=None,
                         do_handshake_on_connect=True,
                         suppress_ragged_eofs=True,
                         ciphers=None,
                         server_hostname=None):

    return SSLSocket(sock=sock, keyfile=keyfile, certfile=certfile,
                     server_side=server_side, cert_reqs=cert_reqs,
                     ssl_version=ssl_version, ca_certs=ca_certs,
                     do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect,
                     suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
                     ciphers=ciphers, server_hostname=server_hostname)

s2 = wrap_socket_with_sni(s1,
                          ca_certs="./pki/signing-dss-cert.pem",
                          cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                          ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
                          server_hostname="localhost")
# ...
```

All I did was copy over the `wrap_socket` helper function, extend it with a `server_hostname` keyword argument, and pass that along to the `SSLSocket` that it returns.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. So, I know little to nothing about Python. I was told ot use it because its easy to use. What, precisely, do I need to do to make python work with SNI?

Comment: This is not so much about Python than about SSL. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with the details of SSL myself, so I can't tell you how to use the API of the `ssl` module. However, I strongly suggest you look at the source code. ` ssl.wrap_socket` looks like a handy utility function that maybe doesn't support all the options it could. You can try replicating what it does, but passing in the `server_hostname` where it is needed.

Comment: @noloader - the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22393062/1350899) to your previous question contains an example using `SSLSocket` instead of `wrap_socket` that should work - at least if [ssl.HAS_SNI](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ssl#ssl.HAS_SNI) is `True`... have you tried that?

Comment: @mata - OK, thanks. Let me try Bruno's example. The example above was based on Python's stuff from their wiki. If anything was going to work, I would have expected the official examples to work.

Comment: @noloader, sorry I wasn't clear, but all this is about what I meant by "*Unfortunately, the server_name parameter isn't in the plain ssl.wrap_socket, only in SSLContext.wrap_socket, but you can use SSLSocket directly.*" When I tried my code, I had initially redefined a `wrap_socket`, but I then realised it probably wasn't worth it. It's probably there for legacy compatibility, considering that creating the `SSLSocket` directly is more or less the same thing.